# Inconsistent dates

Tags: bug

I noticed an account whose profile says “Member for 6 days” but whose question list includes a question from 7 weeks ago. How is this possible?

I can provide a link to the account if requested.

There is a second account with the same name which says “Member for 4 months” but has no questions. (This isn’t a problem. I mention it because there may be a bug related to accounts with the same name.)

Another account says “Member for 26 days” and has questions dated back to 2016.

This account has a century-long suspension. When a user is suspended, does the “Member for” time reset?

Comment: Hmmm... I see I've been a member for over 10 years yet have not asked a question on the main site. Am I in trouble now?

Comment: I think there's a valid point in your question regarding dates, but it needs the *"no question but member for 4 months"* part removed.  There's no requirement to ask questions (or even answer them) to be a member AFAIK.

Comment: @JonCuster I was **not** complaining that someone has had an account for four months without asking a question. I haven’t asked a question in the 26 months that I’ve had *my* account! (And I’m not stupid enough to think that that would be a problem.) My intended point was that there may be a bug related to accounts with the same name. I will edit to clarify this.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine See previous comment.

Comment: I’m not sure how all the various data and dates get reconciled if accounts are merged, for one possibility.

Comment: One possibility (at least in the past): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190267/552049

Comment: @Anyon Thanks! The inconsistent dates are probably due to the merger of sock-puppet accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done any research to find the account you're looking for. But this is the kind of behavior that you might expect if two accounts are merged, if the older account disappears and ownership of its posts is given to the newer account.

Suspensions longer than a year can only be issued by Stack Exchange employees, and generally apply to users who cause problems on multiple sites across the network. Abusing duplicate accounts is one of the ways to earn a multi-year suspension.  The presence of a century-long suspension makes it more likely that the account you describe has been the subject of a merge or other account-ownership shenanigans.